# What is pointer to array of integers

Tags: c, pointers

In this example, what it means? In my opinion in this, to all the address of array `b[]` ,array `a[]` will point correspondingly to all its location ? So do we write it in the following way?

```
int (*a)[10];  
int b[10];  
a = &b;
```

Comment: a is a pointer to an array of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a pointer to an array of `10` `int`s. `a=&b;` means that `a` is pointing to array `b`, i.e, It contains the address of the first byte of `b` which is the address of array `b`.

Comment: so in this example ,there is no connection with b[10],it can be b[5] or any no.....ELSE ......size of both array should be same.

Comment: @Stone; What do you mean by *both array*? There is only one array in your code snippet. `a` is a pointer not an array. And two pointers must be compatible for to be assignable. It means both must have same type and *pointer to array of 10 `int`* is a type that is different and incompatible with type *pointer to an array of 5 `int`*.

Answer (score 0):

It means a is a pointer to an array of 10 ints. The declaration like this where number of elements is specified is used to make pointers to two-dimensional arrays. Like

```
int (*a)[10];
int b[][10];
a=b;
```

If you are creating a pointer to one dimensional array, declaration like this is not necessary. If you have b an array of 10 ints and you want to make a pointer to it simply do this

```
int *a;
int b[10];
a=b;
```

Also & is not necessary on arrays because b is already the address of first element in the array. & is only necessary when you want an address of specific member of the array like `int *a=&b[5];`

Comment: if i write only int (*a)[10]; this means that there is array of 10 ints to which pointer a is going to store address of first int .

Comment: @Stone correct. Just remember int(*a)[10]; allocates only 4bytes for only the pointer itself.

Answer (score 0):

a is a pointer to an array of 10 integers. 
So, for example, a++ will increase a
by the size of int(ie = 4 bytes)

Comment: On most modern machines int is 4 bytes long.

Comment: sorry for previous post.. it will increase by 4 bytes.